# Unstack a dataframe with duplicated index in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Given a toy dataset as follow which has duplicated `price` and `quantity`:

```
  city      item value
0   bj     price    12
1   bj  quantity    15
2   bj     price    12
3   bj  quantity    15
4   bj     level     a
5   sh     price    45
6   sh  quantity    13
7   sh     price    56
8   sh  quantity     7
9   sh     level     b
```

I want to reshape it into the following dataframe, which means add `sell_` for the first pair and `buy_` for the second pair:

```
  city  sell_price  sell_quantity  buy_price  buy_quantity level
0   bj          12             15         13            16     a
1   sh          45             13         56             7     b
```

I have tried with `df.set_index(['city', 'item']).unstack().reset_index()`, but it raises an error: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`.

How could I get the desired output as above? Thanks.

Comment: so, what do you want to do with the duplicates? additionally your output does not match your input dataframe, how does level_a, for bj get the value of 13 ?

Comment: by adding prefix or suffix to column names after reshaped.

Comment: maybe we need to use `pivot-table` or `unstack`?

Comment: Sorry, i don't get it, for non-duplicated one, just keep it, for `bj` and `level`, the value is `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add for second duplicated values `buy_` and for first duplicates `sell_` and change values in `item` before your solution:

```
m1 = df.duplicated(['city', 'item'])
m2 = df.duplicated(['city', 'item'], keep=False)

df['item'] = np.where(m1, 'buy_', np.where(m2, 'sell_', '')) + df['item']

df = (df.set_index(['city', 'item'])['value']
        .unstack()
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

#for change order of columns names
df = df[['city','sell_price','sell_quantity','buy_price','buy_quantity','level']]
print (df)
  city sell_price sell_quantity buy_price buy_quantity level
0   bj         12            15        12           15     a
1   sh         45            13        56            7     b
```

Comment: Maybe it needs to drop `item` for your final `df`, is it `index`?

Comment: yop, it is index name. Give me a sec.